Why is my code returning the full array of data rather than the most common item within the array?
This is my first time posting on stack overflow so if someone can advise if there is more info needed to help.  I am also super new to JS/Programming
I a trying to get the program to pull out the most common word from an array.
function checkData(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) return null;
  const checkingMap = {};
  let maxType = "",
    maxCount = 1;
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let element = array[i];
      if (checkingMap[element] == null) {
        checkingMap[element] = 1;
      } else {
        checkingMap[element]++;
      }

      if (checkingMap[element] > maxCount) {
        maxType = element;
        maxCount = checkingMap[element];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(maxType);
}


There could be an issue with the data source? I have included the data file below:
const dataCheck = require("./medicineData");
const patients = [
  {
    name: "Charlie",
    age: "42",
    allowedMedicine: ["type-a", "type-b", "type-c"],
  },
  {
    name: "Veronica",
    age: "33",
    allowedMedicine: ["type-a", "type-c"],
  },
  {
    name: "Spencer",
    age: "57",
    allowedMedicine: ["type-e"],
  },
  {
    name: "Wolfram",
    age: "74",
    allowedMedicine: ["type-d", "type-a"],
  },
  {
    name: "Jennifer",
    age: "22",
    allowedMedicine: ["type-a", "type-c"],
  },
];
let newArray = [];
let finalMedicineList = [];
function arrangeData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(patients[i].allowedMedicine);
  }
  const mergedArray = newArray.flat(1);
  finalMedicineList.push(mergedArray);

  const array = finalMedicineList;

  dataCheck.checkData(finalMedicineList);
}

arrangeData();


Your function doesn't return anything. Outputting the result to the console is not the same thing as returning something.

So should I return maxType within the function and then conosle.log someplace else?

Yes, where you call the function you should assign the value it returns to some variable

Please also indent your code propperly.

Okay, appreciate your help. I'll keep trying to work on the problem.  I am still pretty new so trying to understand all the terms.

you are declaring const array as local scope that's why you are not able to access array for access array you should simply replace const array with let array and declare it out of function with let newArray = [] ,let finalMedicineList = [].
let newArray = []
let finalMedicineList = []
let array = [];
function arrangeData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(patients[i].allowedMedicine)
  }
  const mergedArray = newArray.flat();
  finalMedicineList.push(mergedArray)

  array = finalMedicineList.flat(1);;

}

otherwise if you don't want to declare array as let then you can declar const a with let newArray = [] ,let finalMedicineList = []. and push finalMedicineList in array
like this
let newArray = []
let finalMedicineList = []
const array = [];
function arrangeData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(patients[i].allowedMedicine)
  }
  const mergedArray = newArray.flat(1);
  finalMedicineList.push(mergedArray)

  array.push(...finalMedicineList[0])
  
}

and you also need to change your upper part code you doesn't need any nested for loop remove the j loop and your code will be look like this:
function checkData(array) {
  if (array.length == 0)
    return null;
  const checkingMap = {};
  let maxType = "", maxCount = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let element = array[i];
    if (checkingMap[element] == null) {
      checkingMap[element] = 1;
    }

    else {
      checkingMap[element]++;
    }

    if (checkingMap[element] > maxCount) {
      maxType = element;
      maxCount = checkingMap[element];
    }
  }
  console.log(checkingMap);
  console.log(maxType);
}

checkData(array)


The main issue is that the result is not being returned. Please do not advise people to create global variables, it is an anti pattern.

Just make sure you return your result rather than console logging it:


function checkData(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) return null;
  const checkingMap = {};
  let maxType = "",
    maxCount = 1;
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let element = array[i];
      if (checkingMap[element] == null) {
        checkingMap[element] = 1;
      } else {
        checkingMap[element]++;
      }

      if (checkingMap[element] > maxCount) {
        maxType = element;
        maxCount = checkingMap[element];
      }
    }
  }
  return maxType;
}

console.log(checkData(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd']));



